# Ubuntu SDK SortFilterModel with variables

Tags: application-development

I'm developing an app for Ubuntu Touch. I have a large list of items in an xml file and access it using the XmlListModel. I would like to offer some filtering on the list (as it is very large). Is it possible to use a variable in the SortFilterModel filter.pattern? Whenever I try to use it I get the error "Unable to assign QQuickText to QRegExp". The app is pretty much all QML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
filter.pattern: new RegExp(t.text)
```

Type of `filter.pattern` is `QRegExp`, type of `t` is `QQuickText`, type of `t.text` is `QString`.

```
filter.pattern: new RegExp("a|b", "i")
// same as
filter.pattern: /a|b/i
```

reference: [Converting user input string to regular expression (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874722/4742108)

Comment: Excellent - works perfectly. Just for completeness, the exact code I have is filter.pattern: new RegExp(filter.text) - where filter is the variable. Many Thanks